# Searching another sheet and obtaining the value.

Tags: google-sheets

I am writing a simmple little application for an evaluation using Google Forms, Sheets, Scripts.

Currently the user goes to a form, and is asked to review an individual (selected from a drop-down list), they then submit their evaluation of that person. The person evaluated then receives an email with a PDF with their evaluation.

Another Google Sheet has the individuals name and email.

I want to "pull" the information from the sheet and use it in the script. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Either use VLOOKUP (formula) to import the emailaddress to the sheet with the form submission and let your email script pick it up from there, or: let your script get the values of that second sheet, loop through them and check for matching names. Info on VLOOKUP(): [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.

I get the following error:
Error: Function VLOOKUP parameter 3 expects number values. But 'me@website.com' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your VLOOKUP. Can you share your formula here ? The 3rd parameter should be the index/column number you wish to retrieve.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(AA26,'Contact Information'!A:A,'Contact Information'!G:G,true)

The A Column is where the name resides, and the G column is where the email resides.I have also tried variations where I use  A2 - A59 (for example) and G2 to G59, and the result is the same.

Comment: Can you share a test sheet here so I can have a look ?